# GetData from multiple Workbooks in the same folder [correct function to add column with wbook name]

Tags: vba, excel

usually i never ask anything mostly because i always find some question similar to mine and the answers are, most of the cases, great, and i just need to adapt.

So, below this is the code i'm using, available on the internet and not created by me.

It is working nice but i would like/need to have, left or right column to the data extracted, the data origin workbook name, is that simple...my knowledge is very basic about vba, and even thinking this should have a easy answer i could not do it yet.

```
Public strFileName As String
Public currentWB As Workbook
Public dataWB As Workbook
Public strCopyRange As String

Sub GetDATA()
Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
Dim strListSheet As String, strCopySheet As String

strListSheet = "List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strCopySheet = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets(strCopySheet).Select
    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Exit Sub

ErrH:
MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not complete."
Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Function LastRowInOneColumn(col)
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
'http://www.rondebruin.nl/last.htm
Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End With
LastRowInOneColumn = lastRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the source file name in Column A, while the data from that file starts in Column B? This should do that:

```
Sub GetDATA()
Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
Dim strListSheet As String, strCopySheet As String

strListSheet = "List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their
 data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0,3)
    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strCopySheet = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets(strCopySheet).Select
    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    'Paste data starting in column #2 (B)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Paste the filename in Column 1 (A) for all the rows just populated
    Range(cells(LastRow + 1,1), cells(LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName),1).value = strFileName
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Exit Sub

ErrH:
MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not     complete."
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The key is the two lines I commented - Paste starting in column 2 instead of 1, then fill column 1 from the last known used row to the current last used row with the name of the file. I was a bit lazy in the example and pasted the full path, but there are plenty of examples on SE and all over Google on extracting just the file name from the path.

Also, I followed the pattern of using `.Select`, however if you modify the code to eliminate all the `.Select` and `ActiveCell` references, it will run much faster.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer, i was trying your code, i'm just not getting the error in this line: Range(cells(LastRow + 1,1), cells(LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName),1).value = strFileName

Comment: it was missing a ) in the end, gonna try it again

Answer (score 0):

What I am thinking you want is for this procedure to append each copied row with the name of the source workbook. I modified your main procedure to do that:

```
Sub GetDATA()
Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
Dim strListSheet As String, strCopySheet As String

strListSheet = "List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
curLastCol = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column    'gets right-most used column

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strCopySheet = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets(strCopySheet).Select
    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    LastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Cells(LastRow + 1, curLastCol + 1).Value = dataWB.Caption        'puts source workbook name
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Exit Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Michael

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, i'm almost sure that i'm really dumb cause i dont get it why when i run the macro, with your changes, after the first wb open it gives error saying that something is missing!